# @libext@ @LDFLAGS@ @LIBCURL_LIBS@ variables not being substituted in clang command when installing pycurl2

Tags: macos, pycurl

I'm trying to install pycurl2 with pip (`pip install 'pycurl2==7.20.0'`), but it's failing on this clang command:

```
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/ed/.pyenv/versions/2.7.17/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sasl build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o -lcurl -o build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/pycurl2.so /usr/lib/libcurl.@libext@ @LDFLAGS@ @LIBCURL_LIBS@
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/libcurl.@libext@'
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '@LDFLAGS@'
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '@LIBCURL_LIBS@'
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

If you look at the last part of the clang command (`/usr/lib/libcurl.@libext@ @LDFLAGS@ @LIBCURL_LIBS@`) it looks like for some reason the installer is not substituting the actual values of LDFLAGS, etc. when generating the command and leaving in the placeholders (marked with @).

Does anyone know what's wrong, or how to fix the clang command?

Comment: Why are you trying to use pycurl2?

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: If you want to use pycurl, you should use pycurl.